# how to get multiple column in one cell from vlookup?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table that might be resumed like this:

```
+--------+-------+-------+-------+  
| id     | info1 | info2 | info3 |  
+--------+-------+-------+-------+  
| 123456 | infoA | infoB | infoC |  
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I'd like to know if with only 1 Vlookup I could get all the info joined in one cell like:
`infoA infoB infoC`

Comment: do you have to use a VLOOKUP? Can't you use a simple ```concat``` function?

Answer (score 0):

So you would be using vlookup based on the id and then you would like to return the concatenated info? You could just use an index/match formula.

`=INDEX($B$2:$B$3&$C$2:$C$3&$D$2:$D$3,MATCH(F2,$A$2:$A$3,0))`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,INDEX(B1:D2,,MATCH("123456",A1:A2,0)))`

This will include a space between the separate values.

It searches the matching value `123456` in column A and from the matching row joins the text values in the range `B:D` from that row excluding empty values and including a space between values.

Comment: Please explain why you down-voted my answer. Have you tried it?

Comment: To use it on bigger range change the range accordingly (for instance): `
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,INDEX(B:D,,MATCH("123456",A:A,0)))`